# how to add custom div in header using wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want this functionality in my custom plugin to show my name in header section right side of logo

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_header');

function hook_header()
{

$output="<?php
    $example_position = get_theme_mod( 'logo_placement' );
    if( $example_position != '' ) {
        switch ( $example_position ) {
            case 'left':
                // Do nothing. The theme already aligns the logo to the left
                break;
            case 'right':
                echo '<style type="text/css">';
                echo '#main-header #logo{ float: right; }';
                echo '</style>';
                break;
            case 'center':
                echo '<style type="text/css">';
                echo '#main-header{ text-align: center; }';
                echo '#main-header #logo { text-align: center; float: none; margin: 0 auto; display:block; }';
                echo '</style>';
                break;
        }
    }
?>";

echo $output;

}
```

I try this but I want to add div right side of logo by custom code

Comment: You want this php code to show on your site?

Comment: i want to show my name on right side of logo when activate my custom plugin it's display right side in header section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You don't need to echo the php code.

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_header');

function hook_header()
{
    $example_position = get_theme_mod( 'logo_placement' );
    if( $example_position != '' ) {
        switch ( $example_position ) {
            case 'left':
                // Do nothing. The theme already aligns the logo to the left
                break;
            case 'right':
                echo '<style type="text/css">';
                echo '#main-header #logo{ float: right; }';
                echo '</style>';
                break;
            case 'center':
                echo '<style type="text/css">';
                echo '#main-header{ text-align: center; }';
                echo '#main-header #logo { text-align: center; float: none; margin: 0 auto; display:block; }';
                echo '</style>';
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to customize header file

Comment: This is not customizing header file. You just echo this using hooks which will change the style. You code will be shown in the place where you have called `wp_head()`

Comment: i mean that it's don't change logo design and menu items locations